# Removing sprites/labels slow in swift (removeallchildren)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, skspritenode, sklabelnode

I am adding sklabelnodes and skspritenodes to the scene with these functions:

```
var levelnode = SKSpriteNode()
var labelLevel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Courier-Bold")

func addlevels(){
    var level = score + 1
    if (level > 0){
        sprite()
        levelnode.position = CGPointMake(frame.size.width / 2.2, -frame.size.height/15.6 - frame.size.height/17.6)
      levelnode.name = "1"
        addChild(levelnode)
         sklabel()
        labelLevel.text = ("1")
        labelLevel.position.x = levelnode.position.x - (levelnode.size.width/40)
        labelLevel.position.y = levelnode.position.y - (levelnode.size.width/6)
        labelLevel.name = "1"
        addChild(labelLevel)
      }
    if (level > 1){
        sprite()
        levelnode.position = CGPointMake(frame.size.width / 1.42 - frame.size.width/100, -frame.size.height/10 - frame.size.height/17.6)
        levelnode.name = "2"
        addChild(levelnode)
        sklabel()
        labelLevel.text = ("2")
        labelLevel.position.x = levelnode.position.x - (levelnode.size.width/40)
        labelLevel.position.y = levelnode.position.y - (levelnode.size.width/6)
        labelLevel.name = "2"
        addChild(labelLevel)
    }
// this goes on and on till level 25
}

func sprite(){
    levelnode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "levelnode")
    levelnode.size.width = frame.size.width / 8
    levelnode.size.height = levelnode.size.width
    levelnode.zPosition = 1
}

func sklabel(){
    labelLevel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Courier-Bold")

    labelLevel.zPosition = 2
    labelLevel.fontColor = SKColor.blackColor()
    labelLevel.fontSize = frame.size.height / 35
}
```

When I am changing the scene, the sprites and labels are removed from the willmovefromview function:

```
override func willMoveFromView(view: SKView) {
    removeAllChildren()
}
```

but this is taking too slow if I compare it with other scenes where even more skspritenodes are added..

I think It has to do with the functions where I add the sprites and labels, but what is wrong about it?

EDIT:
the function that takes me back too the menu:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    errint = false
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {

        let location: CGPoint! = touch.locationInNode(self)

        let nodeAtPoint = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

        if (nodeAtPoint.name != nil) {

            if nodeAtPoint.name == "menu" {
removeallAction()
removeAllChildren()
                var scene1 = GameMenuScene(size: self.size)
                scene1.button = self.button
                scene1.button2 = self.button2
                scene1.button3 = self.button3
                scene1.viewController = self.viewController
                let transition = SKTransition.moveInWithDirection(SKTransitionDirection.Left, duration: 0.75)
                self.view?.presentScene(scene1, transition: transition)

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: anyone out there that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't transitioning to another scene deallocate the current scene?

And if that scene is deallocated, then there's no need for the nodes and such to be removed...

Could you do me a favor, and transition out without removing the children and actions, then transition back in and see if it matters??

Anyway, speed is trivial if you're testing on the simulator... the simulator really only simulates opengl, the core of SpriteKit.

Please try it on your device.

BTW, I'm not sure of stuff but nobody seemed to have answered you so I tried...

EDIT:
HOLY MOTHER OF GOD WHY DIDN'T I SEE THE TIMESTAMP IT WAS ASKED TWO MONTHS AGO.

Too late now I guess... but to anybody reading this, don't answer questions at 2 am.